# Rotating an ellipse about a specific axis

Tags: javascript

I know that the the default rotation in javascript canvas method rotates the image about the Z axis.
Is there a way to show an ellipse about the Y and X axis?

I want something similar to this:

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: canvas is 2D - hence there is no z-axis, unless you're talking about WebGL

Comment: No I am talking about canvas.
I know it doesn't have Z axis, but when we rotate the image it does rotate about the Z axis which is perpendicular on the screen. That is what I mean

Comment: Can you add some code illustrating the behaviour you are describing above? I'm quite sure what you're describing above is not the default behaviour of `ctx.rotate()`

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, you are right, the ctx.rotate() gives different behavior than the attached image.
I need a solution to get a behavior similar to the attached image.

Comment: AFAIK what you need is a mathematical formula that translates rotation to scale commands. In the provided image the circle is scaled continuously giving the *illusion* of rotation.

Comment: I see, thanks.
Do you know the name of this illusion?
Maybe a key word to look for

Comment: The illusion is performed by shrinking the width down to zero and then enlarging it back to it's original value. It simulates rotation to the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you're after.

Keep in mind, this is mostly pseudo-code!

```
var width = 24;
var direction = -1;  

function draw() {

    // Draw a circle
    stroke(50);
    fill(100);
    ellipse(x, y, width, 24);

    width = width + direction; // direction is either 1 or -1

    // flip direction
    if (Math.abs(width) > 24) {
       direction *= -1;
    }
}
```